# How to increase the HMSegmentedControl count?

Tags: ios

hello I am using `HMSegmentedControl` for swipe tab feature. And my code is like this.

```
// Tying up the segmented control to a scroll view
self.segmentedControl4 = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 260, viewWidth, 50)];
self.segmentedControl4.sectionTitles = @[@"Worldwide", @"Local", @"Headlines",@"Four",@"Five"];
self.segmentedControl4.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
self.segmentedControl4.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1];
self.segmentedControl4.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.segmentedControl4.selectedTitleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1]};
self.segmentedControl4.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1];
self.segmentedControl4.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleBox;
self.segmentedControl4.selectionIndicatorLocation = HMSegmentedControlSelectionIndicatorLocationUp;
self.segmentedControl4.tag = 3;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.segmentedControl4 setIndexChangeBlock:^(NSInteger index) {
    [weakSelf.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(viewWidth * index, 0, viewWidth, 200) animated:YES];
}];

[self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl4];

self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 310, viewWidth, 210)];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0.7 blue:0.7 alpha:1];
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(viewWidth * 5, 200);
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(viewWidth, 0, viewWidth, 200) animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label1];
label1.text = @"Worldwide";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label2];
label2.text = @"Local";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label2];

UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth * 2, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label3];
label3.text = @"Headlines";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label3];

UILabel *label4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth * 2, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label4];
label4.text = @"Four";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label4];

UILabel *label5 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewWidth * 2, 0, viewWidth, 210)];
[self setApperanceForLabel:label5];
label5.text = @"Five";
[self.scrollView addSubview:label5];
```

My problem is it doesnt show these label4 and label 5 only show upto 3. But all 5 titles show from the section titles array. How can I solve these problem.
Please help me.
Thanks[This is the github project I used](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `HMSegmentedControl` but i use [Page Menu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) for scroll pages like segment controller. you can add your view controller directly into this menu segment.

I am not sure that this is a perfect answer of this question but it might help others as well.

Comment: I will accept your answer. because it will be help full for someone. and I solved my problem. It was a stupid mistake. I have given the same X value for all those labels :D

Comment: Glade with that you find the solution at any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `self.segmentedControl4.tag = 5;`

Give tag numbers which you want to show in segmentedControl.